React Native Expo custom Dropdown inside a modal not showing up correctly
I recently created a custom dropdown component (code snippet below) following a YouTube tutorial.  The dropdown works great but there is one big styling issue that I cant figure out.  Whenever I click on the dropdown component the dropdown options show up at the top of the screen instead of directly below like a usual dropdown.

The dropdown component is rendered inside of a registration modal. I think the issue is happening because I am rending a modal (dropdown component) inside of another modal (registration modal) but cant figure out a way around it.
import { AntDesign } from '@expo/vector-icons'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { useCallback, useRef, useState } from 'react'
import {
    Dimensions,
    FlatList,
    Modal,
    Platform,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    TouchableOpacity,
    TouchableWithoutFeedback,
    View,
} from 'react-native'

const Dropdown = ({ data, onChange, width = 300, isUsedInsideModal = false }) => {
    const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState()
    const [value, setValue] = useState('')
    const toggleExpanded = useCallback(() => setExpanded(!expanded), [expanded])
    const buttonRef = useRef(null)
    const [top, setTop] = useState(0)

    const onSelect = useCallback((item) => {
        onChange(item)
        setValue(item.value)
        setExpanded(false)
    }, [])
    return (
        <View
            ref={buttonRef}
            onLayout={(event) => {
                const layout = event.nativeEvent.layout
                const topOffset = layout.y
                const heightOfComponent = layout.height

                const finalValue =
                    topOffset + heightOfComponent + (Platform.OS === 'android' ? -32 : 3)

                setTop(finalValue)
            }}
            style={styles.container}
        >
            <TouchableOpacity
                style={styles.button(width)}
                activeOpacity={0.8}
                onPress={toggleExpanded}
            >
                <Text style={styles.text}>{value || 'Select Option'}</Text>
                <AntDesign name={expanded ? 'caretup' : 'caretdown'} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
            {expanded ? (
                <Modal visible={expanded} transparent>
                    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => setExpanded(false)}>
                        <View style={styles.backdrop}>
                            <View
                                style={[
                                    styles.options,
                                    {
                                        top,
                                        width,
                                    },
                                ]}
                            >
                                <FlatList
                                    keyExtractor={(item) => item.value}
                                    data={data}
                                    renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
                                        return (
                                            <TouchableOpacity
                                                activeOpacity={0.8}
                                                style={styles.optionItem}
                                                onPress={() => onSelect(item)}
                                            >
                                                <Text>{item.value}</Text>
                                            </TouchableOpacity>
                                        )
                                    }}
                                    ItemSeparatorComponent={() => (
                                        <View style={styles.separator} />
                                    )}
                                />
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                </Modal>
            ) : null}
        </View>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    button: (width) => ({
        height: 50,
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        width,
        alignItems: 'center',
        paddingHorizontal: 15,
        borderRadius: 8,
        borderColor: '#9E9D9E',
        borderWidth: 1,
    }),
    text: {
        fontSize: 15,
        opacity: 0.8,
    },
    options: {
        position: 'absolute',
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        padding: 10,
        borderRadius: 6,
        borderBottomLeftRadius: 6,
        borderBottomRightRadius: 6,
        maxHeight: 250,
        border: '1px black',
        overflow: 'hidden',
    },
    optionItem: {
        height: 45,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        marginBottom: 10,
    },
    separator: {
        height: 4,
    },
    backdrop: {
        padding: 20,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        flex: 1,
        shadowColor: '#000',
        shadowOffset: {
            width: 0,
            height: 2,
        },
        shadowOpacity: 0.25,
        shadowRadius: 3.84,
    },
})

export default Dropdown

And again this is rendering inside of a modal the structure is something like this:
<View>
  <Modal style={styles.modal} animationType="slide">
    <ScrollView>
      <View>
       <Dropdown/>
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  </Modal>
</View>

Ive tried hard coding the finalValue that sets the top styling property.  By hardcoding it I am able to get it to look correctly for one of the dropdowns but its not dynamic so other dropdowns that are added above or below still dont look right.

I'd made a similar dropdown picker a while ago but it uses reanimated https://snack.expo.dev/SdcxkicOYEGjMdVptjait

I think the reason the y positioning is off is because you have modal within a scroll view; and  the onLayout calls within the modal ignores the scroll view. To fix this, just get the y position of the View containing the dropdown and pass it along to the dropdown component; and since you are already getting the y position you might as grab the x position to neatly align the menus.
Because layouts were being calculated more than once and I already had it on hand, I created a useLayout hook (in typescript):
import * as React from 'react';
import type { LayoutChangeEvent, LayoutRectangle } from 'react-native';

export default function useLayout() {
  const [layout, setLayout] = React.useState<LayoutRectangle>({
    height: 0,
    width: 0,
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
  });

  const onLayout = React.useCallback((e: LayoutChangeEvent) => {
    setLayout(e.nativeEvent.layout);
  }, []);

  return [layout, onLayout] as const;
}

Using onLayout to set the offsets:
<View style={styles.dropdownContainer} onLayout={onLayout}>
    <Dropdown
      data={data}
      yOffset={layout.y}
      xOffset={layout.x}
      onChange={setSelectedItem}
      width={layout.width / 2.5}
    />
    <Dropdown
      data={data}
      yOffset={layout.y}
      xOffset={layout.x}
      onChange={setSelectedItem}
      width={layout.width / 2.5}
    />
  </View>

The Dropdown component:
const Dropdown = ({
  data,
  onChange,
  width = 300,
  isUsedInsideModal = false,
  yOffset = 0,
  xOffset = 0,
}) => {
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState();
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');
  const toggleExpanded = useCallback(() => setExpanded((prev) => !prev), []);
  const [layout, onLayout] = useLayout();
  const buttonRef = useRef(null);
  const insets = useSafeAreaInsets();
  const onSelect = useCallback(
    (item) => {
      onChange(item);
      setValue(item.value);
      setExpanded(false);
    },
    [onChange]
  );
  const top = useMemo(
    () => layout.y + layout.height + yOffset,
    [layout, yOffset]
  );
  const left = useMemo(
    () => layout.x + xOffset,
    [layout, xOffset]
  );
  console.log(layout.x)
  return (
    <View ref={buttonRef} style={styles.container} onLayout={onLayout}>
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.button(width)}
        activeOpacity={0.8}
        onPress={toggleExpanded}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>{value || 'Select Option'}</Text>
        <AntDesign name={expanded ? 'caretup' : 'caretdown'} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
      {expanded && (
        <Modal visible={expanded} transparent>
          <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => setExpanded(false)}>
            <View style={styles.backdrop}>
              <View style={[styles.options, { top, width,left }]}>
                <FlatList
                  keyExtractor={(item) => item.value}
                  data={data}
                  renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
                    return (
                      <TouchableOpacity
                        activeOpacity={0.8}
                        style={styles.optionItem}
                        onPress={() => onSelect(item)}>
                        <Text>{item.value}</Text>
                      </TouchableOpacity>
                    );
                  }}
                  ItemSeparatorComponent={() => (
                    <View style={styles.separator} />
                  )}
                />
              </View>
            </View>
          </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        </Modal>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};

A demo where a Modal has a ScrollView with two dropdown components within it

But also doesnt seem to work to well with multiple Dropdowns in one modal. For example if I add 4 or more the dropdown menu is messed up again.  In the demo you provided you can replicate this by duplicating the Dropdown component a few times over

In the example did you add 'flexwrap:wrap' to the dropdown component?

I havent managed to replicate the issue but its most likely the modal nesting causing problems. I would recommend only using modals for a pop-up like functionality. For an example,  in the Dropdown component you are only hiding/revealing a View; so instead of a modal you can use an absolutely position View who's width and height is tied to the  expanded state

Tbh I dont think creating your own dropdown picker is worth the effort; besides for the learning experience. I created one a while back for funs (here); but more robust and well tested pickers exist; such as react-native-dropdown-picker

Goot point, ill use this one u linked me to instead. Thanks again
